# $L^p$-convergence of $L^p$-bounded martingale on a countable index set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, martingales, uniform-integrability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be countable, $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(M_t)_{t\in I}$ be a real-valued $L^1$-bounded uniformly integrable $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

By the Dunford-Pettis theorem and the Eberlein-Šmulian theorem, $(M_t)_{t\in I}$ is relatively sequentially $\sigma\left((L^1(\operatorname P),L^\infty(\operatorname P)\right)$-compact and hence $$\left(M_{t_n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\xrightarrow{\sigma\left((L^1(\operatorname P),L^\infty(\operatorname P)\right)}M_\infty\tag1$$ for some increasing $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq I$ and $M_\infty\in L^1(\mu)$; i.e. $$\forall Y\in L^\infty(\operatorname P):\operatorname E\left[M_{t_n}Y\right]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\operatorname E\left[M_\infty Y\right]\tag2.$$ From $(2)$ and the martingale property we immediately infer that $$\forall t\in I:\forall A\in\mathcal F_t:\forall n\in\mathbb N:t_n\ge t\Rightarrow\operatorname E\left[1_AM_t\right]=\operatorname E\left[1_AM_{t_n}\right]\tag3$$ and hence $$M_t=\operatorname E\left[M_\infty\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\tag4$$ by $(1)$.

> **Question 1**: Let $\mathcal F_{\sup I}:=\sigma(\mathcal F_t:t\in I)$. How can we show that $M_\infty$ is $\mathcal F_{\sup I}$-measurable?
>
> **Question 2**: If $(M_t)_{t\in I}$ is even $L^p(\operatorname P)$-bounded for some $p>1$, how can we show that $M_\infty\in L^p(\operatorname P)$?

Note that $\bigcup_{t\in I}\mathcal L^p(\mathcal F_t,\operatorname P)$ is a dense subspace of $\mathcal L^p(\mathcal F_{\sup I},\operatorname P)$ which should allow to conclude the desired claim in the first question.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why wouldn't the standard martingale convergence yield $M_{t_n}\to M_\infty$?

Comment: @Shashi Thank you for your comment. What you are missing is that the "standard martingale ($L^p$-)convergence theorem" is precisely what I'm trying to prove here.

Comment: For all $n\geq 0$, $M_{t_n}$ is adapted so it is $\mathcal{F}_{\sup I}$-measurable. Therefore, its limit $M_\infty$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\sup I}$-measurable. Then, you can apply Fatou's lemma to show that $M_\infty$ is in $L^p$. Please let me know if I missed something?

Comment: @charlus Clearly, its pointwise limit is $\mathcal F_{\sup I}$-measurable, but $M_\infty$ is *not* the pointwise limit of $M_{t_n}$ (it only converges in the sense of $(1)$ resp. $(2)$). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you'll need to recover pointwise limits to conclude. You don't want to use the martingale convergence theorem (which you could prove using upcrossings) to get a.s. convergence from (4), is that it?

Comment: @charlus Yes, right. BTW, the claim is made in the proof of Corollary 1.6 here: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~gilles.pisier/ihp-pisier.pdf#page=20.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that you  can recover both your statements by combining elements of the proof of Corollary 1.6 and Theorem 1.5

Comment: @charlus Could you elaborate on that? Maybe even in an answer?

Comment: Apologies, I get your concern. So these martingales are Banach valued?

Comment: @Shashi No, while I finally intend to treat Banach space valued martingales, my question (and corollary 1.6 in the paper above) deal with the scalar valued case.